# Need to strip characters and create a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm creating a frontend layout for dynamic data where I don't have access to the source. Each article contains a section with what could be considered tags.

Each tag can be one or two words and there can be as many as three tags per article.

The code it outputs looks like this:

```html
<div>

            Financial services          Guides      
</div>
```

The tabs, if you're curious, are essentially placeholders for unused tags.

I need to use those tags as a dynamic filter, which will be implemented using data attributes.

My desired goal is to strip out the divs and extra tabs/whitespace and use the tags like this:

```html
<figure data-groups='["Financial services", "Guides"]'>
  /// DATA 
</figure>
```

I've been trying to use various trim or preg_replace functions without any success.

Comment: Use an HTML parser to get the content of those divs.

Comment: @Kelsey Brookes check below code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$data = "<div>

            Financial services          Guides      
</div>";

$data = str_replace("           ",",",$data);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$abc = (string)$dom->getElementsByTagName('div')[0]->nodeValue;
$abc = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $abc));
echo ltrim($abc,',');
```

Comment: Thanks - this generates the following error:

Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array

Comment: Hi @KelseyBrookes use this, `$abc = (string)$dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Comment: Thank you - this actually solves my problem just as effectively, and without the extra step of needing to flatten the array.

Comment: @KelseyBrookes Welcome..:)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DOMDocument` as

```
$html = "<html><head></head><body><div>

            Financial services          Guides      
</div></body></html>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$root = $dom->documentElement;
$getDiv = $root->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($getDiv as $val){
    $res = preg_replace('/(\h){2,}/',',',$val->nodeValue);
    $result[] = array_filter(array_map('trim',explode(',',$res)));
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you, this gets me pretty close in that I can see the print_r result has successfully separated the values into an array:

 `Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => Financial services [2] => Guides ) )`

But attempting to loop through the array to utilise the values generates another error - 

`Notice: Array to string conversion in /item.php on line 65
Array`

Comment: Also, the data is being included from another source and doesn't have html, head or body tags - it's literally just the opening and closing divs that start and end the snippets.

Comment: It'll work without those `html` tags also. And how do you loop through that array can you post that too.

Comment: I've solved the final part by using '$flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $result);' to reduce it to a flat array, since it doesn't need to be multidimensional.

That gets me the output I need.

Thank you.

Comment: But that won't work if you have something like as `<div>

            Financial services          Guides      
</div><div>

            Financial metaphormic services          Guides Makes     
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

First convert parse each div's data 
Second In parsed data convert tabs to space using the code

```html
function tab2space($line, $tab = 4, $nbsp = FALSE) {
    while (($t = mb_strpos($line,"\t")) !== FALSE) {
        $preTab = $t?mb_substr($line, 0, $t):'';
        $line = $preTab . str_repeat($nbsp?chr(7):' ', $tab-(mb_strlen($preTab)%$tab)) . mb_substr($line, $t+1);
    }
    return  $nbsp?str_replace($nbsp?chr(7):' ', '&nbsp;', $line):$line;
}
```

Third convert space separated data in an array. Now you have parsed data in array you can do as your need

[for reference check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308168/using-php-to-convert-tabs-to-spaces-for-html-display)